# Parse Android SDK ParseUser.getCurrentUser() ANR

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-anr-dialog

Upon upgrading to the latest version of the Parse Android SDK, some of my users are experiencing an issue where our app displays a black screen and eventually ANRs and quits. I was able to get the anr traces.txt and found this:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41c1dea0 self=0x41c09768
  | sysTid=31669 nice=-11 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074811220
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=130 stm=12 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x427b26a8> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at bolts.Task.waitForCompletion(Task.java:132)
  at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils.wait(ParseTaskUtils.java:29)
  at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:906)
  at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:893)
  at com.ourapp.activities.LauncherActivity.onCreate(LauncherActivity.java:38)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This occurs after a call to:

`ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();` in LauncherActivity.

This is occurring only with previously authenticated users and after the app has been closed and relaunched. If they have a fresh install (or cleared data) it does not occur. As far as OS versions and devices it varies quite a bit, but I am able to reproduce it every time with a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini (GT-I9190) running 4.4.2 KitKat and also with a Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I545) running 4.4.2 KitKat. I have seen users report this problem from various manufactures and both pre-lollipop and post lollipop though.

Any ideas??

I have already searched their GitHub for known issues and even searched the Parse Discussion Google Group with no luck. (I have since posted this same question in that group)

Comment: fwiw -  the trace is that the bolts.Task.waitForCompletion is blocking and its on the main thread.... so -> anr... can you monkey around with permutations of client and server-side session state and whatever comes into play reconciling the above in the scope of "getCurrentUser()"  ie try diff combos that may recreate the bug?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get debugging to work on those devices either. The debugging process won't attach presumably because of the ANR.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. We had a custom User class extending ParseUser. I had created a method called "isCurrentUser()" which is also the name of a package method in ParseUser. Lint didn't see a problem with it accordingly, but when Parse goes to retrieve the current user it calls isCurrentUser() in the process and the custom method I created was returning unexpected values to the SDK which then caused an eternal lock on the object in bolts. CRAZY. You wouldn't think the SDK would call my method since it is from a class which extends ParseUser, but it does because the User object being saved is of that same instance.